Can "Chance" be considered a metaphysic answer to the question of why evolution and similar happen to be?
So in the realm of evolution, abiogenesis but also Big Bang etc. I often get the explanation that these things happen by chance.
E.g. in evolution, there is the assertion that random mutations are supposed to produce complex biomechanical structures.
While I agree that randomness can play a role to have variations within a species (e.g. different skin, hair color, body mass, etc.) I challenge "chance" as an explanation for new biomechanical features for a species.
The way I see it is that there the scientific evidence for randomness and noise, and there is the metaphysical explanation of chance for why things like abiogenesis happen.
The Main question is:
Is the second type of chance I described not a metaphysical answer of naturalists to "scientific gaps"?
Note: I say "metaphysical", but I simply mean "not scientific" or beyond the scope of what science can answer.
Before someone answers with "Natural Selection":
Natural Selection is also only filtering out specimens that have disadvantageous features but does not explain new features.
Similar to customers demanding a faster and more energy-performing car. The demand does not produce this new car, but some engineer has to sit down and construct and build a new Car that fulfills this demand. Thus using demand to explain why new Cars exist is not accurate or at least not a holistic explanation.
The point I am trying to make with the car analogy is to show that natural selection is a filter, not a mechanism that produces new organisms or features in organisms. In other words: It's not the source of changes.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The Human Observer recognizes patterns. Some patterns are classified as "deterministic". Some patterns are classified as "random". Some patterns are classified as "chaotic". A chaotic system is theoretically deterministic yet its sensitivity to initial conditions produces random evolution of the system in distinct cases. Complex systems are composed of highly interactive subsystems like the human brain, body, nervous system, which is plugged into the complex reality that we imagine exists in our mind generated by our brain.
The complexity of reality and the limitations of pattern recognition seem to be inherent in the minds of Human Observers. This is why I predict that scientists will keep finding that our models all end in the same uncertain or unknown origin that I call The Great Mystery. If a scientist does not yet recognize that God exists as The Great Mystery in our hearts-and-minds (imaginations) then I think God or The Great Mystery has not yet driven these Human Observers sufficiently insane, that is, they have not yet become inwardly sane!

"Herd mentality" - is a huge problem in science. But academia is afraid to talk openly about it.

This is an absolutely legitimate question. But it hits the psychological wall. For many reasons, scientists refuse to explicitly put 'the unknown' outside the scope of research. Instead, they would prefer to deny it or simply don't mention it.
With the theory of evolution, they stubbornly refuse to mix metaphysical with materialistic explanations.
For them, either you believe in God or you believe in Darwin.
As an example I would take this sentence:
"Cosmology should be really desperate. They use something they don't understand (dark matter) to explain something they don't understand at all (dark energy)."

But if chance is metaphysical, as op suggests, then it's clearly not true that "they stubbornly refuse to mix metaphysical with materialistic explanations". Right?

It is never black and white. It is always a mix. For example, in a computer simulator, you would usually have some hardcoded values/logic mixed with randomly generated numbers/logic.

Right, so they don't stubbornly refuse then. They're doing the thing you said they refuse to do.

The question may be "Which" scientists exactly stubbornly refuse and why?

@telion - It is very simple. This question is about to be closed. Similarly, if you try to publish a peer-reviewed paper with a mix of metaphysical and genetic references - you will get a harsh treatment from reviewers.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance  "refuse to explicitly put 'the unknown' outside the scope of research" so why do they insert "chance" then? ("They" referring more to naturalists than scientists I guess) I agree that science and metaphysics shouldn't be mixed but the problem is that chance is used as an explanation therefore I challenge that and say that is a metaphysical explanation in disguise. You are the first one here to at least imply that it is unknown (put 'the unknown') why abiogenesis etc. happened, while others say, obviously chance explains it.

"You are the first one here " - Thank you for complimenting me. But it was debunked by many researchers. Random chance - when applied to creation of a new working protein (on a molecular level) - doesn't survive basic mathematics.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Could you point me to those sources? Thank you very much in advance.

@telion - "The three limitations of Darwin's theory concern the origin of DNA, the irreducible complexity of the cell, and the paucity of transitional species. Because of these limitations, the author predicts a paradigm shift away from evolution to an alternative explanation." https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3246855/#:~:text=The%20three%20limitations%20of%20Darwin's,evolution%20to%20an%20alternative%20explanation.


While I agree that randomness can play a role to have variations within a species (e.g. different skin, hair color, body mass, etc.) I don't accept chance as an explanation for new biomechanical features for a species.

There is not strict differentiation between "variations" and "new features" in science, biology or genetics. The distinction is only made by Creationists to discredit evolution.
Mutations are generally not described by visible changes (hair color and such), but by changes to the DNA. And those happen all the time, plenty of time, typically they are either lethal (to a cell) or inconsequential, with just a few becoming cancer or a change to some function.
Every person is a new recombination of genes from both their parents, unique in that combination in a way the world has never seen before. This recombination of genes could give people completely new features neither of their parents or ancestors had (even though it does not happen often, typically such big changes cause birth to fail). This is one core concept of sexual evolution, just one of many mechanics which can introduce change, with just one type of evolution. There are books written on the subject, and not thin ones either, so don't expect to get a complete explanation of genetics in a couple of sentences on this site.
Trying to understand evolution without understanding genetics first is doomed to fail.

I don't accept chance as an explanation for new biomechanical features for a species.

Evolution as a theory has A LOT of explanations on the internet for all levels of education, so "not accepting" seems more like refusal to learn than an actual argument.
But asking a question while demonstrating refusal to learn seems like bad faith (in more ways than one in this case).

Similar to customers demanding a faster and more energy-performing car. The demand does not produce this new car, but some engineer has to sit down and construct and build a new Car.

That would be a relevant metaphor if babies were made by parents filling out a form specifying their baby. But that's not how babies are made. Ask if you are not sure how that works.
If an image is required can better be understood how mutation plus natural selection generates seemingly "new features", consider wind blowing in a mountainous area with snow. Typically you just get a smooth slightly curved surface as a consequence of the wind blowing away any snow flakes that stand out. But the random mix of snow and ice and wind can sometimes create tunnels or ice caves as "new features" in the landscape, as just a consequence of circumstance of terrain and weather, without anyone having requested a tunnel or a cave anywhere.
Similar natural events that can help those with zero grasp of genetics can be a river that changes its cource many times sometimes building lakes as new features (or tunnels again). Or consider pebbles, which are shaped just by rough rocks rubbing against each other, but eventually generating an overall round and smooth shape as a "new feature", without any rock asking "I want to have a nice smooth skin".

"There is not strict differentiation between "variations" and "new features" in science, biology or genetics." If not there should be. I also had no issue with the "low-level" evolution/variation. If you have a feature that cannot be simplified to have a benefit but requires too many changes in the DNA at once to occur, then that is what I mean by unlikely. As Software-dev I can't randomly change anything in my code without the application to stop working entirely. In biological terms that is what you describe as cancer.

Regarding the Car analogy: The point of the analogy was to show that natural selection is a filter, not a mechanism that produces new organisms or features in organisms. It's not the source of changes. I put it there because I predicted that people would use that as an explanation for novel features in organisms, to keep the focus on "chance".

You also correctly point out that bigger changes cause birth to fail or (I would add) render the individual organism incompatible with other organisms of the same species. In other words, the gene pool of a doesn't have big changes and is relatively stable. What I mean is that there are a lot of small variations in a species and bigger changes don't get very far, making chance unlikely to cause evolution.

"Evolution as a theory has A LOT of explanations on the internet for all levels of education" => correct, and most of them (to my knowledge) are based on chance, which is what I challenge. Admittedly, I guess I should've used the word challenge instead of reject.

DNA is not algorithmic, and in no place does the theory of evolution require change in more than one place at a time. I pointed you to sexual evolution where half the DNA comes from each parent. Maybe you really don't know how babies are made. Other common types of evolution occur via viruses or ingestion of foreign DNA. This is all explained in high school books, and not about philosophy.

DNA is not like software you write, it has many redundancies, such that several random changes do not immediately break the results. As one obvious example, you may have some "broken" gene from your father, but it's function is replaced by a similar gene of your mother. So the cell still works, but the "broken" one can bring about variation. Again, all this is high-schools biology, and it is insulting if you cannot be bothered to even learn high school biology yet write as if you knew all.

The gene pool is "relatively" stable, "small changes", "bigger changes don't make it far". What are your numbers, your evidence? How many genes do you have? How big is the set of all different genes of humanity today? You obviously don't know what you talk about. At all. And still this is science, high-school science, and not philosophy. If you want to talk creationism, the folks at https://christianity.stackexchange.com will welcome you, and tell you all about how science cannot possibly be right, and how Jesus rode on a dinosaur.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have no interest in creationism, it is outdated by at least 100 years, there are no new arguments worth even talking about since 100 years ago. And this is the wrong place, both the questions and the chat are for philosophy, not talking about your preferred book of fairy tales.

Suit yourself. I do have to add though that ad hominems and strawman arguments aren't good philosophy either.
I challenged the notion that chance is a sufficient explanation. I did not assert creationism.

You are ignorant about the science yet you assert evolution is "beyond the scope of what science can answer". So instead of filling your knowledge gaps in science by reading up on biology, you troll a philosophy forum with "challenges". The only people doing that today are creationists. Philosophy is the pursuit of truth, creationism is the spreading of doubt in known truth and spreading of lies. Creationist seek to destroy what philosophy built. There is no place for that here. And no warm welcome from me to people trying that. Play the victim all you want, you came here pushing your beliefs.

ok no. First: the age of an idea or worldview does not determine its (in)correctness. Second, challenging ideas IS part of philosophy and you don't get to pick which ideas get to be challenged or not, even if they're yours. Thirdly, I did not once talk "about [my] preferred book of fairy tales". I challenged "chance" as a sufficient scientific explanation and proposed that chance is used metaphysically. Furthermore: Creationism is a worldview just like Naturalism and I can make the same underhanded attacks you made on Naturalism too ("spreading of lies", etc.), but I will not.

"I can make the same underhanded attacks you made on Naturalism too,  but I will not." I regard your original question as an underhand attack on Naturalism, Science and Philosophy to push the Creationist agenda. So you already did attack.

No. Scientific theories of abiogenesis make no reference to "Chance" as a metaphysical force. There is no evidence or argument presented in the question to support this assertion.
The closest thing to an argument of any kind in the question is the analogy with a car. The analogy is irrelevant because it assumes a teleology. There was no "demand" for prebiotic synthesis of organic molecules, for the formation of proto-cells, etc. Each step happened due to biophysical causes and the ultimate results were irrelevant. Even when natural selection comes in to the picture, at whatever point that was, there is no metaphysical goal to it.
Of course there is a lot we don't yet know about exactly how abiogenesis takes place, but a rejection of naturalism doesn't follow from that.

"Scientific theories of abiogenesis make no reference to "Chance" as a metaphysical force" Of course they don't because science is not metaphysics. My challenge is that they extend the nature of chance so much, that it becomes metaphysical.
"rejection of naturalism doesn't follow from that." agreed, also an acceptance of naturalism doesn't follow either.

I added a clarification regarding the car analogy to the question.

"Each step happened due to biophysical causes and the ultimate results were irrelevant. Even when natural selection comes into the picture, at whatever point that was, there is no metaphysical goal to it." => this is where you either say "irrelevant to science" or if you assert this statement in general, then you make a metaphysical statement. Science only can say what and how something happened. Science cannot make a statements regarding goals.

@telion So then the question is whether goals are apparent, or illusory?

I haven't asked about the nature of goals per se. My question was about the limitation of science regarding chance. Basically, when does scientific chance stop and metaphysic chance start? In a way, the question proposed is asking the same question but regarding goals, one alternative of chance. An interesting question indeed, similar but I think still distinct from mine.

Not to contend or extend the discussion, but my understanding is that physics doesn't include a notion of causality, and so there is no notion of chance either. Not sure if that applies to other areas of science. Maybe it is just pushing it off on to metaphysics because it doesn't belong under science? Asking at the wrong department, I guess?
